Maui скрыть дочерний элемент при нажатии вне его области
У меня есть элемент в котором содержатся кнопки, при нажатии на кнопу они появляются, как обработать скрытие если клик был вне кнопки ?
    <VerticalStackLayout x:Name="addButton" Margin="0,0,20,110" Spacing="20" IsVisible="false">
        <butt:IButton Icon="scan.svg" ButtonText="Кнопка 1" Page="QRAdd"/>
        <butt:IButton Icon="input.svg" ButtonText="Кнопка 2" Page="ManuallyAdd"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>


Сделайте прозрачный задний фон и отрабатывайте клик по нему.

Пробовал делать тригер на всю страницу,  toolkit:TouchBehavior/, но тогда взаимодействие с элементами на страницы становится не возможным отрабатывает тригер постоянно и блокирует выполнение других ивентов. Так же пробовал разместить тригер в <Grid но он отрабатывает не корректно, раз через раз.

Если постоянно блокирует, то значит вы не убираете эту панель при клике. Если мешает взаимодействовать при первом клике, то это как-бы, это то, что вы и хотите, нет? Затемните еще немного для наглядности и будет понятно для пользователя почему клик не проходит.

Решил свой вопрос таким способом - добавил TapGestureRecognizer на все имеющиеся Grid и StackLayout, и сделал проверку на совпадение элемента Ui.
Также, чтобы оставалась прокрутка, убрал TapGestureRecognizer со ScrollView, иначе он перестает работать.
